# Jframe shows multiple times(Java Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Oh hey, I'm a java newbie, I'm trying to make my program shows up a new page called "NewCode" from "SelectTimeAndDate" page by clicking Confirm button from the "SelectTimeAndDate" page. But the NewCode page keep shows up multiple times continuously instead of one time.

Here is my SelectTimeAndDate's code:

```
package car.park.auto.pay.system;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SelectTimeAndDate extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private JTextField hour;
private JTextField minute;
private JTextField second;
private JTextField date;
private JTextField month;
private JTextField year; 

public SelectTimeAndDate() {
    initComponents();


}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    confirmBut = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cancelBut1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    hourField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    dateField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    minuteField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    monthField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    secondField = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    hour2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    hour5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    yearField = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Roy's Car Parking Auto Pay Station System");

    jLabel1.setText("Please input time and date that you are entering:");

    jLabel2.setText("Input time (hh:mm:ss):");
    jLabel2.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    jLabel3.setText("Input date (dd/mm/yy):");

    confirmBut.setText("Confirm");
    confirmBut.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            confirmButActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    cancelBut1.setText("Cancel");
    cancelBut1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cancelBut1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    hourField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            hourFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel4.setText("Hour:");

    jLabel5.setText("Date:");

    jLabel6.setText("Minute:");

    jLabel7.setText("Month:");

    secondField.setText("Second:");

    yearField.setText("Year:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(87, 87, 87)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 128, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(dateField))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(hourField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(confirmBut, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(minuteField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(monthField)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(secondField)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(hour2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                            .addComponent(yearField)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(hour5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                    .addComponent(cancelBut1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(56, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(121, 121, 121))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(hourField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(minuteField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(dateField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(monthField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(hour2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(secondField))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(hour5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(yearField))))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(confirmBut, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(cancelBut1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(28, 28, 28))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(40, 40, 40))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void hourFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

}                                         

private void cancelBut1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    new Menu().setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void confirmButActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String hour=hourField.getText();
    String minute=minuteField.getText();
    String second=secondField.getText();
    String date=dateField.getText();
    String month=monthField.getText();
    String year=yearField.getText();

    if(hour.isEmpty()||minute.isEmpty()||second.isEmpty()||date.isEmpty()||month.isEmpty()||year.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,String.format("Please input all the details!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE));
    }else{
        NewCode.getObj().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();

    }

}                                          




// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton cancelBut1;
private javax.swing.JButton confirmBut;
private javax.swing.JTextField dateField;
private javax.swing.JTextField hour2;
private javax.swing.JTextField hour5;
private javax.swing.JTextField hourField;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField minuteField;
private javax.swing.JTextField monthField;
private javax.swing.JLabel secondField;
private javax.swing.JLabel yearField;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And this is my NewCode's code

```
package car.park.auto.pay.system;


public class NewCode extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private static NewCode obj = null;
static int SetVisible() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}
   public NewCode() {
    initComponents();

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new NewCode().setVisible(true);
    });


   }
   public static NewCode getObj(){
   if(obj==null){
       obj=new NewCode();}
   return obj;
   }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel3.setText("Please NOTE DOWN THIS CODE as when you are LEAVING you are REQUIRE to enter this code to complete the payment.");

    jLabel4.setText("Code generated:");

    jButton2.setText("Finish");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(262, 262, 262)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(234, 234, 234)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)))
            .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(54, 54, 54)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
// End of variables declaration                   


}
```

Please help me discover the problem, thank you!

EDIT: I've found the problem already! I've corrected it by setting

```
 new NewCode().setVisible(true);
```

to

```
 new NewCode().setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Why do you use the invokeLater in your constructor?

Comment: I'm not really sure what that is as I've created the program by using JFrame, therefore many things in there were automatically generated.

Comment: Can you just call setVisible instead of the invokeLater part?

Comment: Looks like I have corrected it by changing 
new Newcode().setVisible(true) to false, thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your constructor

```
 public NewCode() {
    initComponents();

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new NewCode().setVisible(true);
    });
 }
```

You create a new NewCode Object everytime you create a new NewCode object, ending in an endless loop.
Why don't yout simply make the constructor like this?

```
public NewCode() {
    initComponents();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, why do you write the complete package name in front of every swing class? Wouldn't importing them once be easier?

Comment: wow thanks for the solution, it solved the problem of looping